# Spring Returning eagerly cached - a consequence of a circular reference

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, ioc-container, spring-ioc, spring-io

I am working on a problem in one of the application I am working on. I am getting the below error.

```
| DEBUG | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [237] | Returning eagerly cached instance of singleton bean 'cdmManager' that is not fully initialized yet - a consequence of a circular reference
17 Feb 2014 09:31:43,394 | DEBUG | org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory [1307] | Ignoring bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteValidationManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'Full Package of quoteManager' of type [Full Package of Full Package of quoteManager] while setting bean property 'target'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Full Package of quoteManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'onlineManager' while setting bean property 'onlineManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'onlineManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-service.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cdmManager': org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBeanNotInitializedException: FactoryBean is not fully initialized yet
```

I could not able to figure why this error is coming. And I could not able to figure out where the Circular reference present in the Object graph.

FYI  quoteManager has onlineManager and it has cdmManager.

Please help me how to solve this

Comment: You should show your application context.

Comment: What exactly you mean..

Comment: Do you need my applicationContext XML file?

Comment: Yes, it could be useful.

Comment: Problem is it has lot of production code in it.

Comment: It's up to you. Without the xml conf, it's hard to say what the problem can be.